# Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_row() on boolean in | socket connection based PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have total three functions in my one PHP file. My first function is working fine. Second and Third Function have just table name difference else all is fine. When I run second or third function, its giving me error like below

```
Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_row() on boolean in
```

I am getting error in below line of each my last two functions.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
```

I have tested all my query from phpmyadmin and its working fine without any issue.

My full PHP file is like below

```
<?php
require_once("includes/conf.php");


function getAllNumbers() {
    global $conn;
    $sql = "SELECT number from number_list WHERE server=1";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $data = array();
    if($result) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
        array_push($data, $row[0]);
        }
    }
    $response["data"] = $data;
    return $response;
}

function getNewNumbers() {
    global $conn;
    $sql = "SELECT number, id from new_numbers WHERE server = 1";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $newData = array();
    if($result) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
        array_push($newData, $row[0]);
        $id = $row[1];
        $delete = "DELETE number from new_numbers WHERE id = $id";
        $result = $conn->query($delete);

        }
    }
    $response["newData"] = $newData;
    return $response;
}

function getDeleteNumbers() {
    global $conn;
    $sql = "SELECT number, id from delete_numbers WHERE server = 1";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $deleteData = array();
    if($result) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
        array_push($deleteData, $row[0]);
        $id = $row[1];
        $delete = "DELETE number from delete_numbers WHERE id = $id";
        $result = $conn->query($delete);

        }
    }
    $response["deleteData"] = $deleteData;
    return $response;
}

?>
```

Table number_list

```
id  int(11) NO  PRI NULL    auto_increment  
name    varchar(50) NO      NULL        
number  varchar(50) NO      NULL        
server  int(10) NO      0       
status  int(1)  NO      -1      
last_act    timestamp   NO      CURRENT_TIMESTAMP       
user_id int(11) NO  MUL NULL        
created_at  timestamp   NO      CURRENT_TIMESTAMP       
disable int(11) NO      0       
notify  int(1)  NO      1       
fcm varchar(500)    NO      NULL
```

Table new_numbers

```
id  int(11) NO  PRI NULL    auto_increment  
number  varchar(50) NO      NULL        
server  int(10) NO      0
```

Table delete_numbers

```
id  int(11) NO  PRI NULL    auto_increment  
number  varchar(50) NO      NULL        
server  int(10) NO      0
```

I should clear that I am calling these functions every xx minutes from my socket connection based PHP file which I am keep running 24/7 from command line. I think its due to require_once. Let me know if someone can give me hint for solve it.
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

The error states that fetch_row is getting boolean to perform operations. Change your Sql queries.

```
 function getAllNumbers() {
    global $conn;
    $sql = "SELECT number from number_list WHERE server='1'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $data = array();
    if($result) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
        array_push($data, $row[0]);
        }
    }
    $response["data"] = $data;
    return $response;
}

function getNewNumbers() {
    global $conn;
    $sql = "SELECT number, id from new_numbers WHERE server = '1'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $newData = array();
    if($result) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
        array_push($newData, $row[0]);
        $id = $row[1];
        $delete = "DELETE number from new_numbers WHERE id = '$id'";
        $result = $conn->query($delete);

        }
    }
    $response["newData"] = $newData;
    return $response;
}

function getDeleteNumbers() {
    global $conn;
    $sql = "SELECT number, id from delete_numbers WHERE server = '1'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $deleteData = array();
    if($result) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
        array_push($deleteData, $row[0]);
        $id = $row[1];
        $delete = "DELETE number from delete_numbers WHERE id = '$id'";
        $result = $conn->query($delete);

        }
    }
    $response["deleteData"] = $deleteData;
    return $response;
}
```

Moreover this kind of approach is open invitation to Sql Injections. You should use prepared statements

Answer (score -2):

here is the error

$result = $conn->query($delete);

use this instead

```
<?php
require_once("includes/conf.php");


function getAllNumbers() {
    global $conn;
    $sql = "SELECT number from number_list WHERE server=1";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $data = array();
    if($result) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
        array_push($data, $row[0]);
        }
    }
    $response["data"] = $data;
    return $response;
}

function getNewNumbers() {
    global $conn;
    $sql = "SELECT number, id from new_numbers WHERE server = 1";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $newData = array();
    if($result) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
        array_push($newData, $row[0]);
        $id = $row[1];
        $delete = "DELETE number from new_numbers WHERE id = $id";
        $deleted = $conn->query($delete);

        }
    }
    $response["newData"] = $newData;
    return $response;
}

function getDeleteNumbers() {
    global $conn;
    $sql = "SELECT number, id from delete_numbers WHERE server = 1";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $deleteData = array();
    if($result) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
        array_push($deleteData, $row[0]);
        $id = $row[1];
        $delete = "DELETE number from delete_numbers WHERE id = $id";
        $deleted = $conn->query($delete);

        }
    }
    $response["deleteData"] = $deleteData;
    return $response;
}

?>
```

Comment: There two queries in function. Your mentioned line is for second query and I dont think its error

Comment: you replace the $result variable which contain the select query result ( $result = $conn->query($sql);) inside the loop which become an boolean for the next loop you should give another variable name like $deleted = $conn->query($delete); my post showing the correct anser are edited by Apul Gupta to reply the same thing i made the work for free again